# How to do HTTP over an already created socket?

Tags: node.js

I have some networking code that creates sockets, and I would like to do HTTP on them using [Node's standard HTTP API](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Starting like this,

```
var http = require('http'),
    net = require('net');

var port = 12345;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end("Hello world");
}).listen(port);

var sock = net.createConnection({port: port});
```

How do I pass `sock` into `http.get()` or similar?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a custom [http.Agent](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent):

```
var agent = new http.Agent({ maxSockets: 1 });
agent.createSocket = function() {return sock};
http.get({
    host: "localhost",
    port: port,
    path: "/",
    agent: agent}, function(res) {
        // ...
    });
```